# Why is $H_n(M,M\setminus\{x\})$ cyclic?

Tags: algebraic-topology, manifolds, homology-cohomology, orientation

In Hatcher's *Algebraic Topology*, section $3.3$, he defines:

> A local orientation of a manifold $M$ at a point $x$ is a choice of generator $\mu_x$ of the infinite cyclic group $H_n(M,M\setminus\{x\})$.

My question is why is $H_n(M, M\setminus\{x\})$ necessarily cyclic?

I can see this for $M=\mathbb{R}^n$, because by the relative homology sequence we get:
$$H_n(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R}^n\setminus\{x\})\simeq H_{n-1}(\mathbb{R}^n\setminus\{x\})\simeq H_{n-1}(\mathbb{S}^{n-1})\simeq \mathbb{Z}$$ This case is easy because $\{x\}$ and $\mathbb{R}^n$ have trivial homology for $n>0$.

How am I supposed to see this in the general case?

Comment: (This isn't quite the same question as https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1563065/what-exactly-are-the-elements-of-a-local-homology-group , but is solved in the answers there.)

Comment: By excision, reduce to a disk containing $x$.