# need a rigorous proof of the generator of local homology group $H_{n}(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R}^n-\{0\})$ is the given simplex

Tags: homology-cohomology, orientation

My question: Why the generator of local homology group $H_{n}(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R}^n-\{0\})$ is that simplex $\sigma$, where $\sigma=[v_0,e_1,\cdots,e_n]$, $v_0=(-1,-1,\cdots,-1)\in \mathbb{R}^{n}$ $e_i=(0,0,\cdots,1,\cdots,0),i=1,\cdots ,n$.

When I was studying local topological orientation, which is defined by the local homology group.  I meet an important exercise in the book: Prove that the simplex $[v_0,e_1,\cdots,e_n]$ is the generator of local homology group $H_{n}(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R}^n-\{0\})$.

I only know  it is closed cycle in the homology group but don't know how to prove it is a generator. Although [algebraic topology - What exactly are the elements of a local homology group? - Mathematics Stack Exchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1563065/what-exactly-are-the-elements-of-a-local-homology-group) is a little useful, for example it tells me that I can regrad the generator as a ccw or cw orientational simplex / disk. But now no answer tells me a how to prove rigorously  the simplex $[v_0,e_1,\cdots,e_n]$ is the generator of local homology group $H_{n}(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R}^n-\{0\})$.

Look forward to your answer sincerely. Thanks for your reading.

Comment: It boils down to $H_n(\Bbb R^n;\Bbb R^n\setminus\{0\})\cong H_{n-1}(\Bbb R^n\setminus\{0\})\cong H_{n-1}(S^{n-1})$ and understanding what generators of the latter space look like. That much is covered in Hatcher

Comment: Very right. I also realize that the diagram chase of the relative homology long exact sequence helps me find the simplex is mapped to be the generator of the $(n−1)$-th homology group. So the simplex must be a generator. From it , I finally know that the local orientaion is in fact corrsponded to the orientation of the boundary of the the simplex. And in fact, Someone tell me an explaination of Poincare Duality. Cf. Bott. Differential Forms in Algebric Topology. Thanks for your answer.